# Dynamic linear programming code?

Tags: dynamic, linear-programming, online-algorithm

I'm trying to find a "dynamic" linear programming solver.
A dynamic linear programming solver means that an LP solver supporting (very fast) insertions and deletions of the constraints.

I found a paper about a [dynamic LP solver written by David Eppstein](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.9169&rep=rep1&type=pdf),
but I cannot find any implementations.

Is there an implementation of Eppstein's algorithm or similar algorithm?

Comment: Describe your task and why you need this as this sounds as you are either not understanding LP while wanting to use it, or tackling a very specific task without making that clear.

Comment: What I want to do is solving a set of LP problems, say {P_i}.
It will takes O(nm) time if the size of constraints of P_i is m and the number of problems is n. But in my case, each constraints of P_i is not that different, so I want to apply a dynamic LP solver, to get some O(m polylog n) running time.

Comment: Still unclear and your complexity-values given look strange (at least for the general LP-case; be careful when comparing general LPs vs. reduced fixed dimensions problems). So if there is no more well-formulated reason: use any good LP-solver. All of these are able to do very efficient warm-starts (which is the core of Integer-programming anyway). Take this with a grain of salt, but in general: no one cares about theoretical complexity, but empirical performance (or no one would use Simplex).